# FluentNHibernate: can't change key column name for a one-to-many relationship

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, datacolumn

I have an entity:

```
public class Message:Entity
    { 
       public virtual IList`<`Message> ReplayMessages { set; get; }
       public virtual Message ParentMessage { set; get; }
    }

I try to override the mapping:
 mapping.HasMany(x => x.ReplayMessages)
                .AsSet()
                .KeyColumnNames.Add("ParentId");
```

but in the hbm.xml file I get:

```
<set name="ReplayMessages">
      <key column="MessageFk" />
      <one-to-many class="Edi.Core.Model.Message, Edi.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </set>
```

Why the column key name didn't change?

Comment: retagged as "fluent-nhibernate" to use more popular tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use HasMany it looks like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.OrderItems)
    .KeyColumn("OrderId")
    .AsSet()
    .Cascade.All();
```

I don't know what KeyColumnNames is used for...

Comment: I don't get KeyColumn, only KeyColumnNames. Why?

Comment: You need to update your copy of Fluent NHibernate. 1.0 RTM was released a couple of months ago now.